# How can my mac be setup to run both appium/selenium with java and python without conflict?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, python, appium

How can my mac be setup to run both Appium/Selenium with java and python without conflict?

Are there steps I should take and things I should avoid? What things should I look out for?

My mac is setup to work with appium with java, but I want to learn appium with python.

Will it cause conflict if I start setting up with python?

Has anyone else done this with multiple languages using Appium/Selenium?
How did you handle it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Appium and Selenium are both different libraries and hence can be used along side each other on a single Macintosh machine, without any issues.

Things you should avoid is mixing your Selenium tests with Appium tests. Keep both of them in separate folders/repositories.

> My mac is setup to work with appium with java, but I want to learn appium with python.

Absolutely. Follow the steps given in the installation page - if you've Python installed in your Mac (it should by default I think), then you just need to get a good IDE and grab the Appium Python client and get started.

> Has anyone else done this without multiple languages using Appium/Selenium

My current Appium set up uses Python while the Selenium is JavaScript (Protractor to be precise which is a fork of Selenium JS).

All I do it maintain separate repos and directory for both of them. The Appium set up is for the app , which is for the web app, which is automated using Protractor

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So it sounds like it won't interfere with each other. I was wondering if I use Eclipse for both Java and Python development with Appium will it have any problems or confusion.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Eclipse for Python.

Comment: What's a good IDE to use? PyCharm or Atom is better? I like Eclipse showing me where I have errors and it suggesting what can be fixed with. Any IDE that also shows the errors and have suggestions to fix it?